# So nginx is not interpreting folded headers correctly?

Tags: http-headers, nginx, rfc

> HTTP/1.1 header field values can be
> folded onto multiple lines if the
> continuation line begins with a space
> or horizontal tab. All linear    white
> space, including folding, has the same
> semantics as SP. A    recipient MAY
> replace any linear white space with a
> single SP before    interpreting the
> field value or forwarding the message
> downstream.(quoted from [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-2.2))

Here's my server side script,which just dumps the cookie content:

```
var_dump($_COOKIE);exit;
```

Here comes my test,please pay attention to the cookie part:

```
GET /logtest.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; zh-CN; rv:1.9.2.17) Gecko/20110420 AlexaToolbar/alxf-2.11 Firefox/3.6.17
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: zh-cn,zh;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: GB2312,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Cookie: A=t;
 artDate=t
Cache-Control: max-age=0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: iis/8.0
Date: Mon, 23 May 2011 12:38:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=20
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2
Set-Cookie: ZDEDebuggerPresent=php,phtml,php3; path=/

27
array(1) {
            ["A"]=>
                     string(1) "t"
                                  }

0

GET /logtest.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; zh-CN; rv:1.9.2.17) Gecko/20110420 AlexaToolbar/alxf-2.11 Firefox/3.6.17
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: zh-cn,zh;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: GB2312,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Cookie: A=t;
artDate=t
Cache-Control: max-age=0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: iis/8.0
Date: Mon, 23 May 2011 12:38:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=20
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2
Set-Cookie: ZDEDebuggerPresent=php,phtml,php3; path=/

27
array(1) {
            ["A"]=>
                     string(1) "t"
                                  }

0

GET /logtest.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; zh-CN; rv:1.9.2.17) Gecko/20110420 AlexaToolbar/alxf-2.11 Firefox/3.6.17
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: zh-cn,zh;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: GB2312,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Cookie: A=t;artDate=t
Cache-Control: max-age=0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: iis/8.0
Date: Mon, 23 May 2011 12:38:55 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=20
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2
Set-Cookie: ZDEDebuggerPresent=php,phtml,php3; path=/

47
array(2) {
            ["A"]=>
                     string(1) "t"
                                    ["artDate"]=>
                                                   string(1) "t"
                                                                }

0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [known issue](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?29,192093,192093) that doesn't have a high priority.

Comment: One reason for low priority is the deprecation of folding http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p1-messaging-13#section-3.2